# Como multiplicar un Double con un Int TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, python-3.7

Estoy tratando de realizar una grafica que contiene un plano real y otro imaginario. El problema es que al multiplicar con j me sale el siguiente error

```
z=rho*c*((1j*k[f]*a)/(1+(1j*k[f]*a)))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'complex'
```

Este es el codigo que tengo programado

```
import matplotlib as plt
import math
import cmath

a=input("Ingrese el radio de la bocina: ")
rho=1.2
c=340
f=[31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 21000]
k=[]
Zmr=[]
for w in range(len(f)):
      s=(2*math.pi*f[w])/c
      k.append(s)
for f in range(len(k)):
      z=rho*c*((1j*k[f]*a)/(1+(1j*k[f]*a)))
      Zmr.append(z)
plt.title("Impedancia de radiación")
plt.plot(f,Zmr,'b--')
plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Impedancia Mecanica')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varios errores importantes:

- Importas importas `matplotlib` con el alias `plt` pero debes importar `matplotlib.pyplot`:

  ```
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  ```
- `input` en Python 3 retorna siempre una cadena (`str`), debes convertirlo de forma explícita a `int` o `float` según corresponda:

  ```
  a = float(input("Ingrese el radio de la bocina: "))
  ```
- Cuidado con los nombres de las variables, usas `f` para asignarle la lista `[31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 21000]` pero luego haces:

  ```
  for f in range(len(k)):
  ```

con lo que usas `f` como variable asociada al ciclo `for`, que le resigna valores producidos por `range`. esto hace que al final del ciclo `f` está asociada a 10 (`len(k) - 1`) y no a la lista inicial.

No uses range + indizado para recorrer un iterable, usa un for in directamente, es la forma pitónica de hacerlo, además de más legible y eficiente:

```
for w in f:
    s = (2 * math.pi * w) / c
    k.append(s)
```

Tu código puede quedar así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math


a = float(input("Ingrese el radio de la bocina: "))
rho = 1.2
c = 340
fs = [31.2, 63, 125, 250, 500, 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000, 21000]

ks = [(2 * math.pi * f) / c for f in fs]
zmr = [rho * c * ((1j * k * a) / (1 + (1j * k * a))) for k in ks]

plt.title("Impedancia de radiación")
plt.plot(fs, zmr,'b--')
plt.xlabel('Frecuencia (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Impedancia Mecanica')
plt.legend(loc=0)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Comment: zx=zmr.imag
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'imag'

Estoy tratando ahora de separar la parte imaginaria y la parte real, pero me dice que no tengo ese atributo para un objeto de lista. Como puedo solucionar esa parte?

Comment: Debes iterar sobre la lista y aplicar `complex.imag` y `complex.real` sobre cada `item` de la lista. O puedes usar numpy desde el inicio . Si no te es un gran incoveniente, crea una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema, en los comentarios es complicado agregar código porque no mantienen el formato.

Comment: La pregunta ya se formulo, intente de la manera que explicaste pero aun sigo teniendo el mismo problema.